# Arduino Control addressable led WS2812B in chunk of 10

Tags: arduino, led

Hi I want to light up the led strip in chunk of 10 leds, ie LED 0-9 light up with brightness 0-60, and then LED 10-19 brightness 0-60 and so on. Whenever I tried to light up the next 10 it's also change the previous LEDs. TIA for any help!

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define LED_PIN     7
#define NUM_LEDS    60
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
}
void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB ( 0, 0, 255);
    for (int brightness = 0; brightness <=65; brightness++) {
      FastLED.setBrightness(brightness); }
    FastLED.show();
    delay(40);
  }

for (int i = 10; i <= 19; i++) {
    leds[i] = CRGB ( 0, 0, 255);
    for (int brightness = 0; brightness <=65; brightness++) {
      FastLED.setBrightness(brightness); }
    FastLED.show();
    delay(40);
  }
}
```

Comment: `FastLED.setBrightness()` is operating on the strip, not on individual LEDs. Have a look at the FastLED docs for something on `CRGB` `fadeBy()` might work.

Comment: thank you! I'll test it out later.